# Creating dynamic table of contents in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that represents a Page with several SectionHeader components as children of that page. I want to dynamically create a table of contents by inspecting the children of Page that are SectionHeaders.

```
<Page>
  <TaleOfContents sections={this.props.children} />

  <SectionHeader title={"Section A"} />
  <TextBlock>
    <p> Text here. </p>
  </TextBlock>

  <SectionHeader title={"Section B"} />
  <TextBlock>
    <p> Text here. </p>
  </TextBlock>
</Page>
```

Unfortunately, `this.props.children` is undefined. Is there a way to dynamically get these children of Page and render them in TableOfContents?

Edit: Here is my page component. It is really just a big render method to tie a bunch of other components together.

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React = require('react/addons');

// COMPONENTS
var TextBlock = require('../text_block.jsx');
var PaperHeader = require('../header_paper.jsx')
var SectionHeader = require('../header_section.jsx');
var TableOfContents = require('../table_of_contents.jsx');

var Page = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <PaperHeader
        title={"Page Title"}
        authors={["Cole Gleason"]}
        />

      <SectionHeader
       title={'First Section'}
       size={'large'}
      />

      <TextBlock
      key={"text_first"}
      >
      <p>
       Text goes here.
      </p>
    </TextBlock>
   <this.props.activeRouteHandler/>
 </div>
 );
 }
});

 module.exports = Page;
```

Comment: Can you add your Page object?

Comment: You can use Relfux or Flux to do so but your code is incomplete. Please add more code and explain what it is you are doing that you are getting the error.

Comment: Added page component, but there isn't much to it. It is just a way to tie all of the content together. I'm sort of using it in lieu of a templating engine, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the inner components in an array, iterate over them and then render them. Something like this:

```
var React = require('react/addons');

// COMPONENTS
var TextBlock = require('../text_block.jsx');
var PaperHeader = require('../header_paper.jsx')
var SectionHeader = require('../header_section.jsx');
var TableOfContents = require('../table_of_contents.jsx');

var Page = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    var contents = [
      <PaperHeader title={"Page Title"} authors={["Cole Gleason"]} />,
      <SectionHeader title={'First Section'} size={'large'} />,
      <TextBlock key={"text_first"}>
        <p>
          Text goes here.
        </p>
      </TextBlock>,
      <this.props.activeRouteHandler/>
    ];

    var titles = contents.map(function(item) {
      if (item.title && some_other_requirement) {
        return item.title;
      }
      return undefined;
    });

    return (
      <div>
        <TOC titles={titles} />
        {contents}  
      </div>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = Page;
```

**BUT** I can't help but feel like you're not really using React for the right reason and in the right way. You're treating React components like simple templates. Something like this makes more sense:

```
var React = require('react/addons');

// COMPONENTS
var Page = require('../Page.jsx');
var Section = require('../Section.jsx');
var TextBlock = require('../TextBlock.jsx');

var App = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Page title='Page title'>
        <Section title='Section title'>
          <TextBlock>
            <p>Text goes here</p>
          </TextBlock>
          <TextBlock>
            <p>Text goes here</p>
          </TextBlock>
        </Section>
        <this.props.activeRouteHandler />
      </Page>
    );
  }
});

module.exports = App;
```

It's important to give things the right structure. I think this makes more sense because there's now a real relation between parents and children. TextBlocks that belong to a section should be situated inside the section. Now this doesn't solve your table of contents problem but it's a start. It helps, for example, that now all direct children of `Page` are `Sections`, so you could do more with that.

If you want to build a real dynamic table of contents at runtime you should look into another place to store your content. You're mixing templates with content right now, and that's not ideal. Communication in React components really only goes in one way (down the tree), so trying to pass data from a component back to a sibling or parent is not easy nor a good idea. Look into Flux for more about how your data should flow.

Another good read: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0

Comment: Great, thank you! I will look into Flux. I was using React because it seemed like something interesting to learn, but I agree that I'm using a screwdriver to hammer a nail.